# Optimal way to use enums with IN predicate

Tags: postgresql, enums

Postgres 12.

I have an enum like:

```sql
CREATE TYPE state_t AS ENUM('OPENING', 'OPENED', 'CLOSING', 'CLOSED');
CREATE CAST (state_t AS TEXT) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

and a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE files (
...
fstate state_t NOT NULL,
...
);
```

and some query like:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM files WHERE fstate IN ('OPENING', 'OPENED') ...;
```

Sure, the query has a type error, so I rewrote it as:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM files WHERE fstate::TEXT IN ('OPENING', 'OPENED') ...;
```

But then I read good book where the author wrote - "Never cast enums to text, because it leads to performance problems..." (to avoid comparing of texts instead of ints - enums values). So, my question is - obviously, I must cast to avoid the type error, but how to do it in right way, so to avoid ANY performance problem (to do it in the best way)?

Sure, I tried:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM files WHERE fstate::TEXT IN ('OPENING'::state_t, 'OPENED'::state_t) ...;
```

but:

1. I got an error "operator is not unique: state_t = state_t ... HINT: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts"
2. It looks too bloated

So, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how to do it?

Get rid of the cast, then the condition `IN ('OPENING', 'OPENED')` will work just fine

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1fe6cda69d7b1b85a7482bf6439552c5)